# How to call Dynamic Routes in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

http://192.168.0.144/amp/blogs is working But http://192.168.0.144/amp/blogs/1 not working. Please Check below my code.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /var/www/html/dist;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name 192.168.0.144;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/html/dist;
  }
  location /amp/blogs {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.144:8080;

    alias /var/www/html/ro-blog/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env development;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/html/ro-blog/public;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /var/www/html/dist;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name 192.168.0.144;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/html/dist;
  }
  location ~* /amp {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.144:8080/$uri$is_args$args;

    alias /var/www/html/ro-blog/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env development;
    #try_files $uri$args $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/html/ro-blog/public;
  }
}
```